# jquery checkbox change,click event not working with jQuery1.8.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple js where i am showing an alert on click or change event of checkbox. I am using jquery-1.8.2.js library file. The code is working fine in jsFiddle but its not working elsewhere. I am unable to figure out what could be the issue here.

```
<input type="checkbox" id-="chkJS"/><label for "chkJS">click this</label>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chkJS').change(function(){
    alert("changed it");
    });
    $('#chkJS').click(function(){
    alert("clicked it");
    });
});
```

Comment: have you included the Jquery library in your source ?

Comment: `id-="chkJS"` ?

Comment: Please, Accept the answer if you got your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You forget `=` in label declaration and `id-="chkJS"` for input type.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkJS"/><label for="chkJS">click this</label>
```

**OR**

**Your code working fine in `fiddle` because fiddle load jQuery automatically for you and at other you might not load jQuery.**

So please check if jQuery loaded or not.

Comment: @down-voter....care to comment so we can learn from mistakes...?? if you were not cleared in your question then it was not our fault..

Comment: @Kris may be this is the case too..CASE : i was writing answer when comment is posted.. right...and OP does not have only that error see my updated answer..

Comment: thanks alot. corrected it.This would be the biggest blunder in the history of typos. Already wasted a lot of time on this :$

Comment: I had also posted same answer by the time, but ?? deleted answer after this..

We may not answer if correct answer goes negative :)

Comment: @Kris alright we will..and you please continue criticize other and not helping OP...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your input element of `id-="chkJS"` attribute. it should be like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkJS"/><label for="chkJS">click this</label>
```

Demo : [CheckBox demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yhFP6/)

Comment: why downvotes ? have some courtesy to leave a reply . so that we can correct our mistakes :0

Comment: this was a blunder and I coded it correctly on jsfiddle so it was working there. was banging my head like anything. Thanks. I am sorry to not vote you as i don't have the eligibility to vote but thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
id-="chkJS"
```

should be

```
id="chkJS"
```

Comment: this was a blunder and I coded it correctly on jsfiddle so it was working there. was banging my head like anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You code the element was having an hyphen for the id attribute, like id-=, so when the selector searches for the element there is no id for that element. Please change it as follows,

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load('jquery', '1.3.1');
</script>
<body>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkJS"/><label for "chkJS">click this</label>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#chkJS').change(function(){
            alert("changed it");
            });
            $('#chkJS').click(function(){
            alert("clicked it");
            });
        });
        </script>
</body>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: the google.load and all is not necessary if you are adding the js file from your server itself, i did because I use from google libs.